# Careers Stackoverflow not loading JS/CSS/etc

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, javascript

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Here are the error messages in javascript console:

```
Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/cso/all.min.css?398723

Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/cso/Shared/Buttons.css?fffffffff879eaa0

Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/Js/Localization/localization.min.js?398723

Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/Js/all.min.js?398723

Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/Js/third-party/jquery.form.min.js?398723

Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/Js/jobs.min.js?398723

Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/cso/all-print.min.css?398723

Failed to load resource https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers/Img/logo-careers-2-so.png?398723
```

**EDIT**

https://hg.stackoverflow.comcareers it looks like there is a forward slash missing!

thanks @J. Steen

Comment: Is there somehow missing a slash between com and careers, or has the SE network somehow managed to register a new TLD? =D

Comment: Hah, I didn't even notice that.  It looks like that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes We're aware of this and working on it now.

EDIT: This should be fixed now.

Comment: It is!  Site still worked just fine without css/js... good work.