# Stackoverflow Careers Style Sheet not loading

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

Apparently an issue that has happened a couple of times in the past:
[What is happening to StackOverflow? CSS styles aren't loading?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166268/what-is-happening-to-stackoverflow-css-styles-arent-loading)
[Careers Stackoverflow not loading JS/CSS/etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158447/careers-stackoverflow-not-loading-js-css-etc)

[StackOverflow.com not loading properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211748/stackoverflow-com-not-loading-properly)

[CSS for Stack Overflow didn't load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102257/css-for-stack-overflow-didnt-load)

has returned. At least when viewing Careers via Firefox 30.0 on Ubuntu.

It has been doing this for the last week. I've attempted to CTRL +F5 to clear my cache and reload and that hasn't fixed it. I even waited until I was back home (instead of visiting another country) to see if that was the cause.

Interestingly enough it works fine in the Android-App only on PC browser specified above.

**Edit**
Sorry I should have thought of this. 
[image: Screen shot showing Careers site without styling]

Sorry again for the mistake, I think this is what you are looking for:
[image: Network tab from Web Developer Tools]

Ok here's the zoom in you were asking for I think.
[image: Failed 304 errors.]

Here's the Console screen shot:
[image]

**Final Edit (I hope)**
Looks like the problem is only with Firefox 30.0 on Ubuntu. When I used the built-in browser from Lubuntu desktop careers shows up fine. Looks like I'll have to wait until Firefox fixes the problem.

Comment: If you could post a screenshot of the dev console, that would help greatly.

Comment: Sorry Juice, I should have thought of it. The screen shot is now added to the question (bug report).

Comment: @JRSofty Juice asked to see the network tab of the dev tools, to see the failing requests. Can you add it too? (F12 --> Network)

Comment: Almost... can you sort by status, enlarge the messages pane and post the requests that are failing only?

Comment: @JRSofty Click the tab that says console, next to Inspector. That's the screenshot I really need.

Comment: Looks like everything after the jquery.min.js fails if I'm looking at the html correctly.

Comment: @JRSofty another approach, easier: browse directly to http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/all.min.css?v=fba52fd9fef7 then copy and paste the error message you get.

Comment: @ShadowWizard here's what I got from the console **"The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."**

Comment: @Juice see above comment, think it might be server side issue? (no repro for me)

Comment: Just a note, that after performing a CTRL + F5 the two javascript files return a 200 and not a 304.

Comment: @Juice, another thing I just noticed is that I cut off the portion of the console errors showing where they errors occurred. The errors are occurring in "messages:509" and "messages:540".

Comment: @JRSofty What OS are you running. To be honest though. This looks like an issue on your end. Something is causing a timeout to the CDN. Does this happen on other devices connected to the same network?

Comment: @Juice, as I mentioned in the original question I'm using Ubuntu. To be more exact I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @JRSofty I'll load up a VM and test it out. If the VM works for me, unfortunately there's not much I can do.

Comment: Well at least I have my android app :D

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. It was the Privacy Badger add-on for Firefox. It is created by the EFF to help you identify sites that don't handle your privacy so well. Once I disabled it careers came back in full color.

I've reported to EFF that their add-on breaks the careers.stackoverflow.com site.

Comment: Stack Exchange probably have to pay to that company in order to be removed from the black list, or be put into the white list. Those people need to make money after all, no?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The EFF gets enough money from donations.

Comment: I just read their website and there are no lists it triggers depending how the site tracks cookies. Aparantly careers is suspicous because it probably tracks from stack exchange. Even though it is valid for such a site.